# How to determine if an element is at the top of a content block

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I would like to see if there is a way to determine if there is an element at the top of a content block and target that element to preform some CSS. The element I would like to target is an `H2`

So basically I have a content block with content in it like so:

```
<div class="content"> 
    <h2>text<h2>
    <p>text text text</p>

    <h2>text<h2>
    <p>text text text</p>

    <h2>text<h2>
    <p>text text text</p>
</div>

.h2 {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

I would like a way to preform something that says something like

"If an `H2` element exists at the very top of the content `div`, then give it a `padding` of `0`" using jQuery or CSS.

I know you are probably thinking why not just do `.content h2:first-child`?

The reason why I am not doing that is because another content block somewhere else on the site might look like:

```
<div class="content"> 
    <p>text text text</p>

    <h2>text<h2>
    <p>text text text</p>

    <h2>text<h2>
    <p>text text text</p>
</div>
```

And using the `first-child` will give the `H2` that comes after the first paragraph - `p` - a `padding` of 0. I just need the H2 at the very top of the div to have `padding` of 0.

Comment: jQ $('h2:first'); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have tagged jQuery, here is jQuery solution:

```js
$('.content').each(function() {
if($(this).children()[0].nodeName=='H2') {
$(this).children().first().css('color','red'); //set padding in your case
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"> 
<h2>text</h2>
    <p>text text text</p>

<h2>text</h2>
    <p>text text text</p>

<h2>text</h2>
    <p>text text text</p>

</div>

<div class="content"> 
    <p>text text text</p>

<h2>text</h2>
    <p>text text text</p>

<h2>text</h2>
    <p>text text text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Np, glad to help. (CSS solution seems fine too, imho, it should work for all modern browsers, i think). Btw, thanks to downvoter <3 i just posted this as example for jQuery solution... Ego-trips here are reallly strange, but it's human nature, i guess.. :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use `first-of-type` to set the rule then  with adjacent sibling selector `+` you unset the same rule

```css
.content {
  border: dashed green 1px
}
.content > h2:first-of-type {
  background: red
}
.content > p + h2:first-of-type {
  background: transparent
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h2>text</h2>
  <p>text text text</p>
  <h2>text</h2>
  <p>text text text</p>
  <h2>text</h2>
  <p>text text text</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>text text text</p>
  <h2>text</h2>
  <p>text text text</p>
  <h2>text</h2>
  <p>text text text</p>
</div>
```

As @Oriol mentioned, `h2:first-child` will work by itself, you can see his explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41704038/3448527)

See a snippet with only `h2:first-child`

```css
.content {
  border: dashed green 1px
}
.content > h2:first-child {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h2>text</h2>
  <p>text text text</p>
  <h2>text</h2>
  <p>text text text</p>
  <h2>text</h2>
  <p>text text text</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>text text text</p>
  <h2>text</h2>
  <p>text text text</p>
  <h2>text</h2>
  <p>text text text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution this seems to work! But I do like the jQuery solution that was just posted and I might go that route. I gave you an upvote though!

Answer (score 3):

Your premise is false

> And using the `first-child` will give the `H2` that comes after the
>   first paragraph a `padding` of 0

That would happen if you use `h2:first-of-type`. That would select the `h2` after a `p`, yes.

But this won't happen if you use `h2:first-child`. That only selects the `h2` which is the first child. If you have `p` beforehand, then the `h2` won't be the first child, and the `p` won't be a `h2`, so the selector won't match.

So this will do the trick:

```css
.content h2:first-child {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow it seems that you are correct. I feel dumb now!

Comment: I just updated my answer, because I really didn't think about it (I thought OP tested) . Gave you credits and upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can isolate that top block with a class and impact just that one like:

```css
h2 {
  padding: 20px;
}
.content.top h2:first-child {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content top">
  <h2>text</h2>
  <p>text text text</p>
  <h2>text</h2>
  <p>text text text</p>
  <h2>text</h2>
  <p>text text text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target the first element like this

```
body > *:first-child {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

hope i helped you.